# $L^1$ convergence of a sequence of stochastic integrals and convergence of their quadratic variations

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

On a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_t, \mathbb P)$ containing a Brownian motion $W_t$. Let $\sigma^n_t >0$ be a sequence of square intergable adapted processes and consider:
 $$Z_t^n=\int_0^t \sigma^n_s d W_s $$
Assume $Z_t^n$ to be such that:
$$ \langle Z_t^n \rangle = \int_0^t (\sigma_s^n)^2 ds \rightarrow_{L^1(\Omega)} \alpha_t $$

for all $t$ and for some predictable process $\alpha_t$.

Is it true that, for all $t$:
$$  Z_t^n \rightarrow_{ L^1(\Omega) } Z_t $$

where $\langle Z_t \rangle = \alpha_t$?. In other words does the $L^1$ convergence of the quadratic variations imply convergence of the stochastic integrals, and if so is the limit of the quadratic variations the quadratic variation of the limit?

Failing this, does the second statement hold true if we have established the existence of an $L^1$ limit for $Z_t^n$ already? Also I am happy to replace $L^1$ with $L^2$ (or $L^p$).

This seems very much like a Levy theorem/martingale characterization of quadratic variation sort of problem, but I cannot quite handle it.

Comment: the first part is certainly not right, as $\sigma_n = (-1)^n$ shows.  I think the second part is correct.  The martingales in question are $\mathbb L^2$ bounded by the $\mathbb L^1$, and if they converge ptws, they will also converge in $\mathbb L^p, p<2$.  Does this imply $\mathbb L ^{\frac p2} $ convergence of quadratic variation by burkholder-davis-gundy ?

Comment: @mike. Thanks for the nice counterexample. I have a simple proof that this is indeed the case if the the processes $\sigma_t$ themselves converge in $L^1$ (which is sufficient for my purposes), is it best to post it as an answer or edit the question? Even if my proof is correct the case $\alpha_t$ not being absolutely continuous is not covered there.

Comment: @mike Also, what do you exactly mean by "the martingales in question are L2 bounded by the L1, and if they converge ptws, they will also converge in Lp,p<2."? I have looked tat he theorem you mention and I don't think we need such a strong result. I have the TeX for my tentative proof back at my office, I shall post it as soon as I can so you can tell me what you think. Thanks.

Comment: should have said something along the lines of 'they are $\mathbb L^2$ bounded because their quadratic variations are $\mathbb L^1$ bounded, as they are a convergent sequence in $\mathbb L^1$.  I.e., since $\mathbb E (Z_t^n)^2) = \mathbb \int_0^t (\sigma_s^n)^2 ds $ which is converging.'

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I came up with.

Assume <strike>\sigma_t^n \rightarrow \sigma_t</strike> $(\sigma_t^n)^2 \rightarrow \sigma^2_t$  in $L^1(\Omega)$ for all $t$, and let $Z_t= \int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s$. We have, using the monotonicity of $L^p$ norms, the Ito isometry and $(a-b)^2 \leq |a^2-b^2|$:

$$||Z_t^n- Z_t ||_1 = \Big | \Big|\int _0^t (\sigma^n_s - \sigma_s)dW_s \Big | \Big|_1 \leq \mathbb E \left[\int _0^t (\sigma^n_s -\sigma_s)^2 d_s \right]^{1/2} \leq \mathbb E \left[\int _0^t |((\sigma^n_s)^2-\sigma^2_s)| d_s \right]^{1/2}=\left( \int _0^t \mathbb E[ |((\sigma^n_s)^2-\sigma^2_s)|] d_s \right)^{1/2} $$

<strike>Maybe I need some mild extra assumptions to apply</strike> Application of Fubini's theorem in the last line is justified if $\mathbb E \left[ |((\sigma^n_s)^2-\sigma^2_s)| \right]$ is Riemann integrable/continuous (always true for expectations of continuous stochastic processes? No problems of uniform integrability in $\Omega$?).  <strike>Taking the limit inside the integral is ok I believe</strike>  We take the limits in the above, which in the right hand side can be further interchanged with integration because the integrands are continuous and converge pointwise in the $s$ variable by assumption. The $L^1(\Omega)$ convergence of $(\sigma_t^n)^2$ to $\sigma_t^2$ yields that $$Z_t^n \rightarrow_{L^1(\Omega)} Z_t$$

**EDIT**: Edited to answer TheBridge's comments below

Comment: @ Lorenzo : I am not really sure about what you really have proved here. Moreovoer I don't get where you use the $L^1(\Omega)$ convergence of $\sigma_t^n$ hypothesis. What you can be assured of is that dominated convergence assures the ucp convergence of the stochastic integrals. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge. I have edited the answer according to your comments. When you say "What you can be assured of is that dominated convergence assures the ucp convergence of the stochastic integrals" you mean dominated convergence of what? Also, what does the acronym "ucp" mean? - Thanks

Comment: @ Lorenzo : I meant theorem 7 here : http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/properties-of-the-stochastic-integral/

Comment: @The Bridge. Thanks for the useful information. However, it would rather seem to me that ucp is a weaker form of convergence than L^1 (although I have not checked this in detail). I believe replacing $L^1$ convergence of $\sigma_t^n$ with the $L^1$ convergence of $(\sigma^n)^2_t$ should do the trick; as you noted $\sigma_t^n$ is insufficient to conclude in the estimates above. Is the answer still unclear now? I am not claiming this is the optimal requirement in any way however.

Comment: The inequality $(a−b)^2 \le |a^2 − b^2|$ is not true. Take for example $a=1$ and $b=−1$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are positive, maybe I didn't make it explicit

Comment: @Marcel; to fully address your correct remark: looking closely the problme is less general: I have to restrict to $\sigma_t^n >0$ for all $n$. I have edited the question; note that now TheBridge counterxample $\sigma_t^n >-1^n$ no longer applies